# Displaying GeoServer Mapbox Vector Tiles with a custom Gridset

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, tiles, vector-tiles, gridsets

I'm trying to render Mapbox Vector Tiles hosted on a GeoServer instance. I followed along with the [GeoServer Vector tiles tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) without any issues (the demo uses EPSG:900913). Likewise, I'm able to preview the MVT in *Tile Caching > Tile Layers*. See Image #1 below. The tiles also rendered in OpenLayers when I set my map view projection to EPSG:90013.

The projection I need to use in OpenLayers is EPSG:6931. [I added this projection as a new gridset following these instructions](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/gridsets.html#) and then assigned it to the same layer (opengeo:countries). However, I get nothing when trying to preview my MVT in this projection. See Image #2 below.

When I plug this url into OpenLayers with the following code (using React), The vector layer doesn’t render on my map, similar to the GeoServer preview.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const tileGrid = new TileGrid({
    extent: [
      -180.0, 51.208333333333364, -61.09935709635414, 83.2172339545356,
    ],
    tileSize: 256,
    resolutions: defaultResolutions,
  });

  const layer = 'opengeo:countries';
  const projection_epsg_no = '6931';
  const vtLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
    style: new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#ADD8E6',
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#880000',
        width: 1,
      }),
    }),
    source: new VectorTileSource({
      tileGrid: tileGrid,
      projection: 'EPSG:6931',
      format: new MVT(),
      url:
        'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
        layer +
        '@EPSG%3A' +
        projection_epsg_no +
        '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',
    }),
  });
  if (olMaps[mapKey]) {
    console.log(vtLayer);
    olMaps[mapKey].addLayer(vtLayer);
  }
  return () => {
    if (olMaps[mapKey]) {
      olMaps[mapKey].removeLayer(vtLayer);
    }
  };
}, [olMaps, mapKey]);
```

This is just the test data from the GeoServer demo but the actual data I want to render has the same behavior in the MVT GeoServer preview; showing up in EPSG:900913 and displaying nothing in the new gridset with EPSG:6931.

Is there a way to retile my vector data in the correct projection so it can be ingested by OpenLayers? Is there a re-projection step I need to do? What am I missing?

---

#### Image #1: MVT Preview with default gridset EPSG:900913

[image: MVT Preview with default gridset EPSG:900913]

#### Image #2: MVT Preview with new gridset EPSG:6931

[image: MVT Preview with new gridset EPSG:6931]

Comment: As the message suggests you must specify the same projection as options in both the view and the VectorTileSource (both default to EPSG:3857)   You will also need to specify the custom tilegrid in the VectorTileSource.  Similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tiles-4326.html

Comment: Thanks @Mike -- I was able to get rid of the OpenLayers error, but similar to the GeoServer gridset preview, the vector layer doesn't display on my basemap.

Comment: With a non-standard grid the `{-y}` placeholder in the url may not work correctly and you may need to replace it with a `tileUrlFunction` similar to that in described at tbe top of https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html  Also check that your `defaultResolutions` are appropriate for the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of troubleshooting, I realized that the min and max *Published Zoom Levels* in GeoServer kept defaulting to 0 for the gridset I added.

I simply removed the gridset from the assigned layers, saved, and added them again. One thing to note-- I added my resolutions in the *Tile Matrix Set* of the gridset config **after**  initially assigning the girdset to the corresponding layers. It's possible that this was the root of my issue and the layers did not see the changes I had made to the gridset, however it may have been some error I made in the layer/gridset configuration. Working beautifully now!